# Single action only occurring on last instance of loop (but rest of actions in loop working as expected)

Tags: vba, excel

I have an Excel VBA macro that copies contents between files and sheets.  One of the things that it does is copy content from a template into new sheets and then fills in the information on those sheets from other files.  That's all working as expected.  What's not acting as expected is the code to delete the buttons and shapes carried over from the template sheet into the information sheets.  That code is within a for loop that acts on each page, yet it only is deleting these shapes from the last page while leaving them in place on every other page the loop touches. Everything else in the loop affects every page as expected.

The relevant section of my Macro is as follows. `masterWB` and `currentWB` are two separate workbooks:

```
For k = 1 To masterWB.Sheets.Count
    j = k + 1

    ' Removed because irrelevant to this query:
    ' Copying of content from other workbooks to each sheet
    ' Copying of formatting to all lines with content within sheet
    ' All of this is still working as expected on every sheet.

    ' Deletes button copied from first (template) sheet
    currentWB.Worksheets(j).Shapes.SelectAll
    Selection.Delete

Next k
```

Comment: Trying to select shapes may require selecting the sheet first.  Perhaps try adding the following `currentWB.Activate` and `currentWB.Worksheets(j).Select` before the line `currentWB.Worksheets(j).Shapes.SelectAll`?

Comment: `currentWB` or `masterWB`? If they are intended to be different, does `currentWB` contain one more worksheet than `masterWB`

Comment: @Demetri Yup, that's worked! I just added the `currentWB.Worksheets(j).Select` line and it's now working!  Thanks for that! Can you please write that as an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: As it looks right now to me, he copies something to `currentWB.Worksheets(j)` earlier without any errors... that way we may need more informations...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Trying to select shapes may require selecting the sheet first. Perhaps try adding the following currentWB.Activate and currentWB.Worksheets(j).Select before the line currentWB.Worksheets(j).Shapes.SelectAll

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure why you are looping through `masterWB`, but the shape delete operation relates to `currentWB` (as Jeeped states above), but try deleting the shapes directly rather than selecting them:

```
currentWB.Worksheets(j).Shapes.Delete
```

If that doesn't work, a separate loop perhaps:

```
Dim sht as worksheet
For each sht in currentWB.Worksheets
    sht.shapes.delete
next sht
```

Something else worth noting - you are looping through sheets, but referring to worksheets by the same number. The Sheets collection contains worksheets, charts, macros, forms and other stuff - do you have any of these?

Hope this helps!

Comment: Good point. 'For i = 2 to currentWB.Worksheets.Count' then, and 'currentWB.Worksheets(i).Shapes.Delete' in the loop.